# XML tagname starting with number is not working

Tags: xml

I want to update the component 870Jars atrribute values using Jenkins build.
When i open the xml file in IE, I am getting the below error

Error:- 
The XML page cannot be displayed

### Cannot view XML input using XSL style sheet. Please correct the error and then click the Refresh button, or try again later.

A name was started with an invalid character. Error processing resource 'https://svn.retailerinfo.com/svn/Stores/Po...

<870Jars>
---^

XML file:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Application> 
<app-name>Regist</app-name>
<baseline-version>Regist_R11.6.0.51</baseline-version>
<app-version>v11.6.0.51</app-version>
<defversion>1.0.0</defversion>
<component>
    <870Jars>
    <filename>v10.3.0-870Jars.zip</filename> 
    <targetfilename/> 
    <version>v10.3.0</version> 
    </870Jars>
</component>
</Application>
```

Is there any way where i can start a tag name with a number ?

I used `&lt;/870Jars&gt;` in place of <870Jars> but it is just printing the value rather than working as tag

Answer (score 24, accepted):

An XML element whose name starts with a number is *illegal* XML. You should not start with numbers.

> XML elements must follow these naming rules:
>
> - Names can contain letters, numbers, and other characters
> - Names cannot start with a number or punctuation character
> - Names cannot start with the letters xml (or XML, or Xml, etc)
> - Names cannot contain spaces
>
> Any name can be used, no words are reserved.

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp

[Specification Details.](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-name)

Comment: But i have to use it as per the requirement.I tried with hexadecimal <_x0038_70Jars> in place of <870Jars> but it is not working.Not sure what i am missing here

Comment: @user2935276 escape sequences do not work in tag names. There is no easy way to say this but if your requirement is to a) use XML and b) violate XML then your requirements are very wrong. If this is an existing file format, my best suggestion is to edit the document to be valid xml before parsing it, and then edit it to match your file format after saving.

Answer (score 0):

Simple workaround is to {concat('_',data(desired_tag_name_here))} and filter out the first character elsewhere if it is a lodash. A tidbit hacky, but when CData and other methods are either too dirty or make the code unreadable, just tag a note by the concatenation, fix it with the next handler, and move on about your business

Answer (score -4):

Try using a CDATA like below:

```
<component>
    <![CDATA[    
    <870Jars>
    <filename>v10.3.0-870Jars.zip</filename> 
    <targetfilename/> 
    <version>v10.3.0</version> 
    </870Jars>
 ]]>
</component>
```

Comment: CDATA means: this isn't XML; while it'll represent that 870Jars sequence, that can't be parsed as XML and can't contain `]]` sequence

Comment: Agreed with Rubens - using CDATA here is a BAD idea as it prevents standard (ie xpath) parsing of the contained tags, eg. version