# MySQL: How can I find all the XML tokens from one MySQL field in an XML string?

Tags: mysql, xml

I have a mysql table field (skills_rebus) containing an XML string.

The string look like: "<42>yes</42><37>yes</37><36>yes</36>"

Let's call each "<x>yes</x>" a token.

I have another string ($my_skills) extracted from another table containing the text: "<42>yes</42><38>yes</38><17>yes</17><25>yes</25><37>yes</37><47>yes</47><31>yes</31><30>yes</30><28>yes</28><29>yes</29><51>yes</51><54>yes</54><3>yes</3><4>yes</4><36>yes</36>"

The I need to find all the rows from the first table where the tokens from skills_rebus ALL occur in $my_skills.

I can do it the other way with a bunch of "AND skills_rebus LIKE '%<x>%'" - but for the life of me I can't figure out how to do it in reverse.

ALL of the skills_rebus tokens must appear in $my_skills and they're all out of order.

Any assistance from MySQL gurus would be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: There are some problems with this 'xml'-strings: their are not valid xml because tag names cannot start from numbers. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19677458/2253302

Comment: Cheers, Alexander.  It's only in that format so that it's easy to convert to a PHP array and back again.

Comment: If this format can be changed in real xml with some additional requirements before saving to database It could be passible to write query in sql, but not now.