# XPath compiling behaviour

Tags: java, xml, exception, xpath, transformer-model

I am testing my application and realised that behaviour is different when compiling.

For example, if my expression to compile is :

```
XPathExpression expr = xPath.compile("/DocDetails/TransactionSignature");
```

And :

```
XPathExpression expr2 = xPath.compile("/DocDetails/" + x);
```

x is declared as a String datatype.

Lets say that x in expr2 is "abc", XPathExpression is compiled with no issues.

But if x in expr2 is "123abc" OR "123", XPathExpression throws a :

> javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: A location step was expected
>   following the '/' or '//' token.

Just curious regarding this behaviour..

Here is the full code for reference:

```
        String document = "C:/Users/Eunice/Documents/MITS/doc.xml";
        String document2 = "C:/Users/Eunice/Documents/MITS/doc2.xml";

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(document);

        Document doc2 = builder.parse(document2);

        XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xPath = xPathFactory.newXPath();
        XPathExpression expr = xPath.compile("/DocDetails/TransactionSignature");
        Node node = (Node)expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE);

        String x = node.getTextContent();

        System.out.println(x);

        XPathExpression expr2 = xPath.compile("/DocDetails/" + x);
        Node node2 = (Node)expr2.evaluate(doc2, XPathConstants.NODE);

        if (node2 == null)
            System.out.println("null");
        else 
            System.out.println("not null " + node2.getTextContent());
```

And this is the XML file:

```
<DocDetails>
    <TransactionSignature>abc123</TransactionSignature>
</DocDetails>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer after much searching!

It is actually illegal to start an element tag with numbers.

As can be seen in [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19677458/10684298)

Originally, this line was throwing an transformer exception:

```
        XPathExpression expr2 = xPath.compile("/DocDetails/" + x);
```

Since it is illegal to start with numbers, they are probably reading it as an invalid tag.

Which means this line is actually reading "/DocDetails/" instead of "/DocDetails/123" OR "/DocDetails/123abc",

causing the extra '/' at the end, hence throwing an transformer exception.

Answer (score 0):

> But if x in expr2 is "123abc" OR "123", XPathExpression throws a

XML element name cannot start with number. Hence your example is equivalent to

```
XPathExpression expr2 = xPath.compile("/DocDetails/123abc");
```

I guess XPath parser does not expect it.

You should also provide full XML. I believe it certainly does not contain anything like `<DocDetails><TransactionSignature>abc123</TransactionSignature><123abc>something</123abc></DocDetails>`. This is simply invalid XML.

Comment: Thanks for your input Tomas for ur answer! Also, I just shared a part of a dummy XML and know that its probably logically wrong/invalid.