# Newtonsoft.Json DeserializeXmlNode changes tag name from number to "something"

Tags: c#, json, .net, xml, json.net

We have a long living app that uses some feed that used to be xml, but was converted to json...
Of course we were "to lazy" to change parser from reading XmlDocument to read JObject or other so we used "DeserializeXmlNode" to convert from json txt to XmlDocument.
All was fine for a long long time... until we updated from Newtonsoft.Json versions 4.5 and 6.0 to version 12.0.x and suddenly we started to have some problems...

let's say json looks like this:

```
{"version":"2.0","result":[{"mainobid":"123","typeId":"2","subobjects":{"1":{"data":"data"},"2":{"data":"data"}}}]}
```

what we used to get was xml having

```
<1><data>data</data></1><2><data>data</data></2>
```

tags

now... instead of <1> tag we get something like <*x0031*>
instead of 10 there's _x0031_0
instead of 45 there's 0x0034_5
and instead of 100 _x0031_00

Can I turn that off somehow? or am I forced now to change parsing to decode that sick *x003.*... thing?

INB4 1: I realize that having 1: and <1> is not the thing that anyone sane wishes to have, but i can't change that, it's external feed

INB4 2: I know we should change parsing from xml to json, but as above - some lazines and re-using old code that was working 100% good.

EDIT:

```
private static void TestOldNewton()
{
    var jsonstr = "{\"version\":\"2.0\",\"result\":[{\"mainobid\":\"123\",\"typeId\":\"2\",\"subobjects\":{\"1\":{\"data\":\"data\"},\"2\":{\"data\":\"data\"}}}]}";
    var doc = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(jsonstr, "data");
    Console.WriteLine(doc.OuterXml);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

using packages.config like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.1" targetFramework="net48" />
</packages>
```

and receiving output:

```
<data><version>2.0</version><result><mainobid>123</mainobid><typeId>2</typeId><subobjects><1><data>data</data></1><2><data>data</data></2></subobjects></result></data>
```

freshly compiled and run on new, testing project.

Comment: XML with an element name that starts with a numeral is not well-formed, see [XML tagname starting with number is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19677315/3744182).  If Json.NET was writing such XML before, it was writing malformed XML.

Comment: Actually, what version of Json.NET were you using?  If I try with 7.0, an exception is thrown *`Invalid name character in '1'. The '1' character, hexadecimal value 0x31, cannot be included in a name.`*, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/p8BXpE.  If I try with Json.NET 8, the element names are escaped and well-formed XML is returned, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/aYtheZ.  Can you share a [mcve] where `<1><data>data</data></1>` is actually generated?  Even version 4.5.11 from 2012 throws, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/qRvKA2.

Comment: I've been using 4.5 and 6.0 in this project (yeah, ancient) and now it's 12.0

Comment: Can't reproduce with 4.5.1 either, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/zTM6hq.  The issue has nothing to do with Json.NET, it is that `XmlWriter` itself won't write malformed XML.  Were you also using a really old version of .Net itself?

Comment: and... as mentioned, i realize it IS wrong - and actually i don't care that much it was/is wrong.
i don't need to have that xml perfect with xml rules. i would like to have that consistent with the xml i used to be getting from feed (obviously wrong).
and even if it's really important to make it <something_number> it's sick to make as they do ( i'd be happy to have it like <xnumber> not <_x003[firstdecimal]_[all other decimals]>)

Comment: *i don't care that much it was/is wrong* - OK.  But it would still be helpful to know how you previously generated that XML, because I can't generate it with any version of Json.NET on .Net core or .Net 4.7.2.  If we knew how you did it before it might be easier for us to tell you how to restore that behavior.  Were you also using an older version of .Net?

Comment: @dbc see edit on the post - i just created new project with 6.0.1 version under 4.8 .NET (same was for 4.6.2) and the result has <1> and <2> tags, not <_x0031_> etc

Comment: Confirmed, demo here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/3Nu5EQ.  My previous fiddles used `XmlWriter.Create()` to write XML with indentation -- which was what was throwing the exception, not the `XmlDocument` construction itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The cause of the change** is the following checkin: *[Fixed converting JSON to XML with invalid XML name characters](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/commit/45936d58a2b773d1c01bded3e9b87e9e7f72e0a2)* to Json.NET [8.0.1](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/8.0.1).  This checkin added (among other changes) calls to [`XmlConvert.EncodeName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlconvert.encodename) inside [`XmlNodeConverter.CreateElement()`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/666d9760719e5ec5b2a50046f7dbd6a1267c01c6/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/XmlNodeConverter.cs#L2058):

> ```cs
> private IXmlElement CreateElement(string elementName, IXmlDocument document, string? elementPrefix, XmlNamespaceManager manager)
> {
>     string encodeName = EncodeSpecialCharacters ? XmlConvert.EncodeLocalName(elementName) : XmlConvert.EncodeName(elementName);
>     string ns = StringUtils.IsNullOrEmpty(elementPrefix) ? manager.DefaultNamespace : manager.LookupNamespace(elementPrefix);
>
>    IXmlElement element = (!StringUtils.IsNullOrEmpty(ns)) ? document.CreateElement(encodeName, ns) : document.CreateElement(encodeName);
>
>     return element;
> }
> ```

This was done to *[[add] support for converting JSON to XML with invalid XML name characters](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/8.0.1)*.  This applies here because **element names beginning with numerals such as `<1>` are not well-formed XML element names**, as explained in *[XML tagname starting with number is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19677315/3744182)*.  And in fact the XML you were previously generating was not, strictly speaking, well-formed XML.

As you can see from the code excerpt above, there doesn't seem to be a way to disable this change and create elements names without encoding them.

**As a workaround**, since you want to create elements with numeric names like `<1>` anyway, you could subclass [`XmlTextWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmltextwriter) and decode the names as they are written by calling [`XmlConvert.DecodeName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlconvert.decodename?view=netcore-3.1)

> This method does the reverse of the EncodeName(String) and EncodeLocalName(String) methods.

First define the following class:

```
public class NameEditingXmlTextWriter : XmlTextWriter
{
    readonly Func<string, string, string> nameEditor;

    public NameEditingXmlTextWriter(TextWriter writer, Func<string, string, string> nameEditor)
        : base(writer)
    {
        this.nameEditor = nameEditor;
    }

    public override void WriteStartElement(string prefix, string localName, string ns)
    {
        var newLocalName = nameEditor(localName, ns);
        base.WriteStartElement(prefix, newLocalName, ns);
    }
}
```

Then use it as follows:

```
var doc = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(jsonstr, "root");

var sb = new StringBuilder();
using (var textWriter = new StringWriter(sb))
using (var writer = new NameEditingXmlTextWriter(textWriter, (n, ns) => XmlConvert.DecodeName(n)))
{
    doc.WriteTo(writer);
}
var outerXml = sb.ToString();
```

Notes:

- You must subclass the deprecated `XmlTextWriter` instead of its replacement [`XmlWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwriter) because `XmlWriter` will throw an exception on an attempt to write a malformed XML element name such as `<1>`.
- As an alternative, since Json.NET is currently licensed under the [MIT License](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/LICENSE.md), you could fork your own version of `XmlNodeConverter` and remove the calls to `XmlConvert.EncodeName()` from `CreateElement()`.  However, this solution seems less desirable as it creates a maintenance requirement to keep your forked version up-to-date with Newtonsoft's version.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VcntcE).