# XSLT transformation to read line item data and use it to create dynamic header element

Tags: xslt

Advice to convert the input xml into desired output where i need to read SalesQuoteParty line item data and create element name dynamically by concatenating rolecode id to each line item record field. here is an example input and output xml data.

**Input xml Data**

```
<SalesQuote>
<ValidToDate>2021-09-13T00:00:00.000</ValidToDate>
<RoleCode_PSMText>Sold-To Party</RoleCode_PSMText>
<SalesOrganisationID>50042604</SalesOrganisationID>
    <SalesQuoteParty>
    <SalesQuoteParty>
        <PartyName>1001_Test1_Partner</PartyName>
        <RoleCode>1001</RoleCode>
    </SalesQuoteParty>
    <SalesQuoteParty>
        <PartyName>Manish</PartyName>
        <RoleCode>39</RoleCode>
    </SalesQuoteParty>
    </SalesQuoteParty>
</SalesQuoteParty>
```

> Output XML Data

```
<SalesQuote xmlns="urn:pros:o-series:tps:7:0">
<RoleCode_PSMText>Sold-To Party</RoleCode_PSMText>
<SalesOrganisationID>50042604</SalesOrganisationID>
<BuyerPartyID>436764</BuyerPartyID>
<ZApprovalStatusNES_SDKText>Not Started</ZApprovalStatusNES_SDKText>
<1001_PartyName>1001_Test1_Partner</1001_PartyName>
<1001_RoleCode>1001</1001_RoleCode>
<39_PartyName>Manish</39_PartyName>
<39_RoleCode>39</39_RoleCode>
```

Comment: Where does the BuyerPartyID come from in your output? Also your input is not valid XML, it does not have a root element.

Comment: thank you for looking into it, BuyerPartyID can be ignored, i created the xml manually to put out the requirement, original xml is huge. also root element can be added. I am struggling in xslt on how to created dynamic element name concatenating the RoleCode

Comment: In XML an element name cannot start with a number : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19677315/xml-tagname-starting-with-number-is-not-working. (So for example 1001_PartyName is not valid XML.)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, in that case i will try to add a  fixed character before the RoleCode.

Comment: i was able to get my requirement achieved with this xslt: